# Same command is used more than one number of time but i am getting only last output

Tags: formatting, titles

I am defined `\editor{strong text}` and `\reviewer{strong text}` command is used more than one number of time. But, I am getting only last `\editor{Some Text}` command output.

My class file defined this command below mentioned way:

```
\def\@editor{}
\def\editor#1{%
     \gdef\@editor{\raggedright \textbf{Edited by:}\newline #1}}

\def\@reviewer{}
\def\reviewer#1{%
     \gdef\@reviewer{\raggedright \textbf{Reviewed by:}\newline #1}}

\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 50pc%
\vbox{\hbox to 0pt{\vbox to 0pt{\vskip -40pc%
\begin{minipage}[b]{10pc}
{\@editor\par}
    \vskip 1.5em%
{\@reviewer\par}
    \vskip 1.5em%
{\@correspondence\par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
{\@metanote}%
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{12pt}
\begin{minipage}[b]{31pc}  
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\raggedright\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont\color{colorA}\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
%      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
        \raggedright\@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\@abstract\par}
    \vskip 1em%
    {\@keywords\par}
    \vskip 1em%
    {\@firstpara\par}
   \end{minipage}}}}%
  \par
  \vskip 8.5em}
```

My TeX File Coding is below mentioned:

```
\editor{Wagner L. Ara\'{u}jo, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\editor{Kannan L. juvio, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\reviewer{Jedrzej Jakub Szymanski, Max Planck Institute of Molecular Plant Physiology, Germany }
\reviewer{Dimas Mendes Ribeiro, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
```

I am not changing the coding structure because my `.tex` file is using another conversion process. My **problem is** the output only **print the last editor output.** I don't know how to print the **each editor and reviewer**. Kindly provide the solution to print the **more than number of editors and reviewer**.

My output looks like is:

[image: Editor Reviewer detail tex output image]

Comment: please use the `{}` button in the editor for code blocks, and `\`...\`` for inline code

Comment: `\editor` in that class is just defined to be used once, it deos not typeset anything, it simnply saves the text in a macro to be used by `\maketitle`. So if you use it twice it over-writes the macro

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[!b]{10pc}` is an error you can not use `!`

Comment: Kindly provide simple example for above mentioned problem sir... I can't get the solution

Comment: You have defined `\editor` and `\reviewer` macros in a overwriting manner, so obviously you get only the value from last call.

Comment: Any other way to get the required output

Comment: Please help us to help you and complete your code so that we have a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and suggest solutions when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You are just providing unusable fragments of code so it is hard to help but the intention of that class is presumably that you use `\editor{someone and someoneelse}` not `\editor{someone}\editor{somoneelse}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you *don't* add the meta caption "Edited by:" to the macro that gathers the meta information like

```
\newcommand{\editor}[1]{\def\@editor{\raggedright \textbf{Edited by:}\newline #1}}
```

Note that I used the LaTeX command `\newcommand` for the top-level meta macro (it's preferable!) and that `\gdef` isn't needed for the definition of the internal meta storage, i.e. `\@editor`; `\def` is sufficent.

In your case you can use a meta command that incremets the internal storage as

```
\newcommand{\editor}[1]{\edef\@editor{\@editor #1}}
```

To make the least changes to your alredy existing setup the end version looks like

```
\newcommand{\editor}[1]{\protected@edef\@editor{\@editor\newline#1\vspace{3pt}}}
```

The complete code is given in the end. You will see that a few changes were inevitable. On this occasion I also cleansed the overall code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\let\@editor\@empty
\newcommand{\editor}[1]{\protected@edef\@editor{\@editor\newline#1\vspace{3pt}}}
\let\@reviewer\@empty
\newcommand{\reviewer}[1]{\protected@edef\@reviewer{\@reviewer\newline#1\vspace{2pt}}}
\let\@correspondence\@empty
\newcommand{\correspondence}[1]{%
  \protected@edef\@correspondence{\@correspondence\newline#1\vspace{2pt}}}
\def\@maketitle{%
  \vspace{50pc}%
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    \textbf{Edited by:}\vspace{3pt}
      \@editor
    \par\vspace{1.5em}
    \textbf{Reviewed by:}\vspace{3pt}
      \@reviewer
    \par\vspace{1.5em}
    \textit{Correspondence:}\vspace{3pt}
      \@correspondence
    \par\vspace{1.5em}
    \@metanote%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace{12pt}%
  \begin{minipage}{.66\textwidth}
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \let \and      \newline
    \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\textwidth}}
      {\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont\color{blue}\@title} \\[1.5em]
      {\large \@author} \\[2em]
      {\small \@abstract} \\[1em]
      Keywords: \@keywords \\[1em]
      \@firstpara
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  \vskip 8.5em}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%auxiliary macros (not provided in the MWE!)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\abstract}[1]{\def\@abstract{#1}}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\def\@keywords{#1}}
\let\@firstpara\@empty
\let\@metanote\@empty
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother

\editor{Wagner L. Ara\'{u}jo, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\editor{Kannan L. juvio, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\reviewer{Jedrzej Jakub Szymanski, Max Planck Institute of Molecular Plant Physiology, Germany }
\reviewer{Dimas Mendes Ribeiro, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\correspondence{Jana Doe, University of TeX Wizardry}
\author{John Doe}
\title{Multiple usage of meta macros}
\abstract{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.}
\keywords{Lorem, Ipsum, Dolor, Sit}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: @SaravanakkhumarC, the usual way to say "thanks" is to use the upvote and accept buttons :)

Answer (score 4):

As said in some comments, the current definitions of `\editor` and `\reviewer` are meant to set the content and each overwrite the previous one.

Here is a simple a simple definition (using the list processing facilities of the `etoolbox` package, i.e., use `\RequirePackage{etoolbox}` or `\usepackage{etoolbox} to load it).

```
\newcommand{\@editor}{}
\newcommand{\@reviewer}{}

\newcommand{\editor}[1]{\listadd{\@editor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\reviewer}[1]{\listadd{\@reviewer}{#1}}
\newcommand{\printeditor}{Edited By:\newline\dolistloop{\@editor}}
\newcommand{\printreviewer}{Reviewed By:\newline\dolistloop{\@reviewer}}
```

In this way the command `\editor{some text}` and `\reviewer{some text}` add their argument to lists of editors (stored in `\@editor` and `\@reviewer`). The two commands `\printeditor`  and `\printreviewer` loopover the list and print the content of the respective lists.

For the example, replace  `\@editor` and `\@reviewer` with `\printeditor` and `\printreviewer` in the given definition of `\maketitle`.